# How to use query inside a function and apply to other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe user and calls where common column is user_id. I need to drop values in user dataframe where churn is not null and remove those user_id rows in calls.

```
users = user_id,first_name,last_name,age,city,reg_date,plan,churn_date
1000,Anamaria,Bauer,45,"Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Roswell, GA MSA",2018-12-24,ultimate,
1001,Mickey,Wilkerson,28,"Seattle-Tacoma-Bellevue, WA MSA",2018-08-13,surf,
1002,Carlee,Hoffman,36,"Las Vegas-Henderson-Paradise, NV MSA",2018-10-21,surf,
1003,Reynaldo,Jenkins,52,"Tulsa, OK MSA",2018-01-28,surf,
1004,Leonila,Thompson,40,"Seattle-Tacoma-Bellevue, WA MSA",2018-05-23,surf,
1005,Livia,Shields,31,"Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA",2018-11-29,surf,
1007,Eusebio,Welch,42,"Grand Rapids-Kentwood, MI MSA",2018-07-11,surf,
1008,Emely,Hoffman,53,"Orlando-Kissimmee-Sanford, FL MSA",2018-08-03,ultimate,
1009,Gerry,Little,19,"San Jose-Sunnyvale-Santa Clara, CA MSA",2018-04-22,surf,
1010,Wilber,Blair,52,"Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA",2018-03-09,surf,
```

```
calls = id,user_id,call_date,duration
1000_93,1000,2018-12-27,8.52
1000_145,1000,2018-12-27,13.66
1000_247,1000,2018-12-27,14.48
1000_309,1000,2018-12-28,5.76
1000_380,1000,2018-12-30,4.22
1000_388,1000,2018-12-31,2.2
1000_510,1000,2018-12-27,5.75
1000_521,1000,2018-12-28,14.18
1000_530,1000,2018-12-28,5.77
1000_544,1000,2018-12-26,4.4
```

I want to create a function so that I can apply to other dataframes consists only of user_id after filtering out in original users dataframe. I want to drop the other user_id's in other dataframes too

Answer (score 0):

You can try with simple filtering using [`.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
def filter_calls_df(user_id_df, calls_df):

    # filter out churn user_id
    usr_id = user_id_df.query("churn_date.notna()")['user_id'].unique()

    # filter calls dataframe
    calls_df = calls_df.query("user_id not in @usr_id")
    
    return calls_df
```

Comment: how do I apply this to calls and other dataframes as function uses two arguments?